# Cloudfront CORS only works for subdomain

Tags: nginx, amazon-s3, cors, cdn

I'm with a very strange behavior with CORS using Cloudfront + S3

When I run

```
curl -I -s -X GET -H "Origin: https://myapp.com" https://s3.amazonaws.com/myapp/assets/fontawesome-webfont.woff | grep Access
```

and

```
curl -I -s -X GET -H "Origin: https://**www.**myapp.com" https://s3.amazonaws.com/myapp/assets/fontawesome-webfont.woff | grep Access
```

Both return the values as expected:

> Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://musicjungle.com.br
>
> Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET Access-Control-Expose-Headers: ETag
>
> Access-Control-Max-Age: 3000 Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
>
> Vary: Origin, Access-Control-Request-Headers,
>
> Access-Control-Request-Method

But when I try to run the same curl using the Cloudfront URL, just the www subdomain works

```
curl -I -s -X GET -H "Origin: https://www.myapp.com" https://d1bfllp5zjnl7u.cloudfront.net/assets/fontawesome-webfont.woff | grep Access
```

> Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://www.musicjungle.com.br
>
> Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, HEAD
>
> Access-Control-Max-Age: 3000 Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true

The below command doesn't return the headers as expected

```
curl -I -s -X GET -H "Origin: https://myapp.com" https://d1bfllp5zjnl7u.cloudfront.net/assets/fontawesome-webfont.woff | grep Access
```

Any ideia why this could be happening? I already allowed Origin for both servers on S3 CORS configuration (as we can see above), but it seems to be something on Cloudfront configuration, that only allows "www.myapp.com".

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, I'd say it's a matter of CloudFront's Request Headers cache settings...

> By default, **CloudFront** doesn't consider headers when caching your objects in edge locations. If your origin returns two objects and they differ only by the values in the request headers, CloudFront caches only one version of the object.

– [Source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/header-caching.html#header-caching-web).

So, go to your *Distribution* and edit your *Behavior* to allow CloudFront to cache objects based on the values of the `Origin` headers:

[image: CF Headers Cache Configuration]

After new settings are established, create an *Invalidation* for the affected files.

Comment: Important tip about creating an invalidation to bust the cache